# Configurar atalho no vs code para indentação

Tags: visual-studio

sou novo nisso, então, perdão se eu errar no post. Minha dúvida aparenta ser simples, mas eu não estou desenrolando.

Basicamente, é como configurar um atalho no VSCODE para indentação nos meus códigos.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Segundo o Key Bindings, no windows você usa <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

No Mac é <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

E no Linux é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

E se tu quiser customizar, [veja esses passos.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_customizing-shortcuts)

Fonte:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua resposta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar no conteúdo sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [Bate-papo do Stack Overflow em Português](http://chat.stackexchange.com/). Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [Stack Overflow em Português Meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: Valeu mano! Consegui configurar aqui e deu de boas! obrigado novamente!

Answer (score -2):

No meu VS code instalei uma extensão pra identar HTML em PHP. Achei muito legal e prático.

Nesta extensão o comando é: Ctrl + Alt + F

Segue o Link da extensão:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rifi2k.format-html-in-php